# HTML Video with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog

Would like to find a way to work around this.

Currently do have modal block which is formed by JavaScript, all style elements present in css file. Modal appears only after click on item, JS takes reference and files path from original HTML and places them in modal created inside JS code.

Question is, how and which way to change from image to video file, to keep it same wait that JS gets and process all the information?
JS suppose to take only path to file and form video tags, like with image.

Reference of code and issues.

HTML Code

```
<dt><a href="#" class="rm-viewdetails" data-thumb="images/13.jpg">Gourmet Yam Taohu</a></dt>
                                    <dd>Thai tofu salad yam taohu</dd>
```

JS CODE

```
viewDetails = function( recipe ) {

        var title = recipe.text(),
            img = recipe.data( 'thumb' ),
            description = recipe.parent().next().text(),
            url = recipe.attr( 'href' );

        var $modal = $( '<div class="rm-modal"><div class="rm-thumb" style="background-image: url(' + img + ')"></div><h5>' + title + '</h5><p>' + description + '</p><a href="' + url + '">See the recipe</a><span class="rm-close-modal">x</span></div>' );

        $modal.appendTo( $container );

        var h = $modal.outerHeight( true );
        $modal.css( 'margin-top', -h / 2 );

        setTimeout( function() {

            $container.addClass( 'rm-in rm-nodelay' );

            $modal.find( 'span.rm-close-modal' ).on( 'click', function() {

                $container.removeClass( 'rm-in' );

            } );

        }, 0 );

    };
```

Comment: can't find the code for the video, if you can add those will be able to help you.

Comment: Here for the same, don't know how to put with JS, but should be kept in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but it sounds like you're trying to play a video when the user clicks an element that contains an image. If so, you could use the HTML5 `video` element, which has a built-in `poster` attribute to contain a placeholder image.  (See [HTML5 video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) for details.)

You'd just add a `source` element (with its own `src` attribute set to your video's path) inside the video element, give the video element the `controls` attribute, and wait for the user to click the built-in play button. (Note that some browsers require the video source to be formatted as mp4. ). To avoid compatibility problems between browsers, define multiple video types (multiple `source` elements)

Comment: Thank you for the guide, will try to do that way, trying to do auto play programmable on open. Should be simple.